# Why is this coordinate ring integral over $k[x]$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $f(x, y) := \sum_{j=1}^{n} a_{j}(x)y^{j} \in k[x,y]$, with $k$ algebraically closed. The natural map $$\phi: k[x] \rightarrow C_{f} := k[x,y]/(f)$$ is injective when $f(x, y) \neq cx+d$ for $c, d \in k$, and when $\phi$ is injective we can extend it: $$k(x) \rightarrow k(Z_{f}) := (\text{ring of rational functions on variety determined by } f); \\ g(x)/h(x) \mapsto \phi(g(x))/\phi(h(x)).$$
The field $k(Z_{f})$ is isomorphic to $k(x)[y]/(f)$ and is thus a finite field extension of $k(x)$ of degree $\deg_{y}(f)$ (the degree of $f$ in the variable $y$).

**When $a_{n}(x) = 1$, the ring $C_{f}$ is an integral extension of $k[x]$.**

Maybe a silly question, but why is this true? How can I find a monic polynomial in $k[x][w]$ which vanishes on a given element $g \in C_{f}$, and why would this depend on the leading coefficient $a_{n}(x)$ of $f$?

Comment: When $a_n(x)=1$, $\overline y\in C_f$ satisfies a monic equation, so is integral. Thus $F_f=k[x][\overline y]$ is integral.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Okay, so is the ring $F_{f}$ the same as the ring $C_{f}$ ?

Comment: It's a misprint....

Answer (score 0):

When $a_{n}(x) = 1$, the element $\overline{y} \in C_{f}$ satisfies the monic $f(x, y) \in k[x][y]$. Therefore $C_{f} = k[x][\overline{y}]$ is integral over $k[x]$.